# How do I pan and zoom an image?

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout

I'm trying to get some basic pan and zoom functionality for images. The stateless version can display images (rotated 180 degrees by Transform) and the Scale events show up in the logs, but that's it.

Is `GestureDetector` the correct widget for getting the pan/pinch/spread events? Should I be looking at Transform, Animation, or should I just be modifying the fields inside the `Image` widget?

### Stateless version

```
// Wraps an Image widget to provide pan and zoom functionality.
class InteractiveImage extends StatelessWidget {
  InteractiveImage(this._image, {Key key}) : super(key: key);

  final Image _image;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new Center(
      child: new GestureDetector(
        onScaleStart: (ScaleStartDetails details) => print(details),
        onScaleUpdate: (ScaleUpdateDetails details) => print(details),
        onScaleEnd: (ScaleEndDetails details) => print(details),
        child: new Transform(
          transform: new Matrix4.rotationZ(math.PI),
          alignment: FractionalOffset.center,
          child: _image,
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

### Stateful version (doesn't work)

```
// Wraps an Image widget to provide pan and zoom functionality.
class InteractiveImage extends StatefulWidget {
  InteractiveImage(this._image, {Key key}) : super(key: key);

  final Image _image;

  @override
  _InteractiveImageState createState() => new _InteractiveImageState(_image);
}

class _InteractiveImageState extends State<InteractiveImage> {
  _InteractiveImageState(this._image);

  final Image _image;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    setState(() => print("STATE SET\n"));
    return new GestureDetector(
      onScaleStart: (ScaleStartDetails details) => print(details),
      onScaleUpdate: (ScaleUpdateDetails details) => print(details),
      onScaleEnd: (ScaleEndDetails details) => print(details),
      child: new Transform(
        transform: new Matrix4.rotationZ(math.PI),
        alignment: FractionalOffset.center,
        child: _image,
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

### Update (library solution)

**Use https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/zoomable_image**

(And maybe help me add physics and elastic edges?)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I'm not sure what you mean by "doesn't work" but you're on the right track.

Check out https://github.com/flutter/flutter/blob/master/examples/layers/widgets/gestures.dart for a working example of a widget you can pan, pinch, and scale.

Comment: how does the gesture scale work?  I didn't understand how to test it. I can tap, double tap and long press.  I can drag the object.  Is that scale?  I think of scale as zoom in.

Answer (score 94):

You can use [InteractiveViewer](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/InteractiveViewer-class.html) which comes out of the box with Flutter.

```
@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  return Center(
    child: InteractiveViewer(
      panEnabled: false, // Set it to false
      boundaryMargin: EdgeInsets.all(100),
      minScale: 0.5,
      maxScale: 2,
      child: Image.asset(
        'your_image_asset',
        width: 200,
        height: 200,
        fit: BoxFit.cover,
      ),
    ),
  );
}
```

Comment: Note that this only available from Flutter 1.20.0 onwards.

Comment: @PeterWauyo awesome, but after zooming in, i cant move image right  or left from my single finger, i have to use 2 fingers to move?

Comment: works. but when use with multiple images in ListView, it is sluggish to scroll down.  after using for few minutes, the app crashed.

Comment: i got it.. instead use InteractiveViewer for every images, i wrap ListView with InteractiveViewer. no more sluggish or crashed. perfect solution for me. thx

Comment: @codetinker You may also try `InteractiveViewer.builder`.

Comment: Why setting panEnabled to false?!!

Answer (score 6):

Based on the code from the question and encouraged by Collin's answer, this is what I came up with:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:vector_math/vector_math_64.dart';

class InteractiveImage extends StatefulWidget {
  InteractiveImage(this.image, {Key key}) : super(key: key);

  final Image image;

  @override
  _InteractiveImageState createState() => new _InteractiveImageState();
}

class _InteractiveImageState extends State<InteractiveImage> {
  _InteractiveImageState();

  double _scale = 1.0;
  double _previousScale = null;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    setState(() => print("STATE SET\n"));
    return new GestureDetector(
      onScaleStart: (ScaleStartDetails details) {
        print(details);
        // Does this need to go into setState, too?
        // We are only saving the scale from before the zooming started
        // for later - this does not affect the rendering...
        _previousScale = _scale;
      },
      onScaleUpdate: (ScaleUpdateDetails details) {
        print(details);
        setState(() => _scale = _previousScale * details.scale);
      },
      onScaleEnd: (ScaleEndDetails details) {
        print(details);
        // See comment above
        _previousScale = null;
      },
      child: new Transform(
        transform: new Matrix4.diagonal3(new Vector3(_scale, _scale, _scale)),
        alignment: FractionalOffset.center,
        child: widget.image,
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

While it seems to work, it would be great to get confirmation or correction from someone inside the Flutter team.

(Also, this only allows for zooming. Panning is not implemented.)

**EDIT:** Edited to reflect [Collin's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43651708/how-do-i-pan-and-zoom-an-image/43862909?noredirect=1#comment74784701_43862909) and his [his more detailed explanation](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43874673/763935). But note there is still an open question with regards to private `setState()` and private fields that don't immediately affect the rendering.

Comment: Your State should not take any constructor arguments. Use widget.image instead. Make your State's mutable member fields private (starting with _) and make sure to always modify them in a setState() block.

Comment: I updated my question with a solution for panning + zooming, although it doesn't let you zoom in past 1:1 pixels so it only works for large images. Might be possible to combine our approaches.

Comment: Combined yours with mine and factored it out into a library with an adjustable scale factor. See updated question.

Comment: Have you added panning yet?

Comment: @alex351: Sorry, no. But perlatus made his version into a library which seems to very usable and does have panning: https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/zoomable_image

Comment: This library no longer works with Flutter v1.7.8+hotfix.4, and the repository has been archived so no issues can be filed against it.  I would recommend searching pub.dev/flutter for libraries that suit your needs.