# Keeping final fields on the Widget or the State?

Tags: dart, flutter

Where should one keep final values?

In the `StatefulWidget` (my subclass of course) instance and access it from the `State` (subclass) via `widget.thatFinalField`, or

In the `State` itself. I've seen both approaches already.. Any pros and cons for each of them?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You should store `final` member fields (which are passed via constructor arguments) on the `StatefulWidget` and make them public.

The `StatefulWidget`'s associated `State` should use only the default constructor (no arguments), and its member fields should be private (starting with a `_`) and mutable. Initialize them inline or in `initState` if expensive or async work is necessary.

This pattern allows the `StatefulWidget` to be recreated/rebuilt with new constructor arguments when its parents call `setState`, while re-using the previous `State` and letting it keep the values stored in its mutable member fields.

Comment: What about final stream subscriptions? Obtained from services or injector classes.

Comment: Constructing your StatefulWidget and its associated State should not have any side effects. If you're doing any work that has side effects to initialize your widget, you should be doing it in initState() and saving it to mutable member variables. Make sure to clean up after yourself in dispose().