# why state class of StatefulWidget should be private in flutter

Tags: flutter, statefulwidget

As I learned that state of StatefulWidget widget in flutter defined as private and both of snippet of VS Code , and android studio do this like below on _RectAnsState

```
class RectAns extends StatefulWidget {
  final String title;
  const RectAns(this.title, {Key key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _RectAnsState createState() => _RectAnsState();
}

class _RectAnsState extends State<RectAns> {
  Color _color = Colors.transparent;

 
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container()}
}
```

although i pass GlobalKey to widget so i can use this key to get currentState object , but i need to define that currentState object type from other files , but it's type is private class then its must be public here, what wrong of my implementation

```
GlobalKey gk = new GlobalKey();
RectAns rectAns = new RectAns(count.toString(), key: gk);
```

and on other file i want to get this state to call function inside and setState

```
RectAnsState rt = gk.currentState
```

above RectAnsState is private , so is the correct way to make it public?????

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can remove `underline _` to make it `public`
You can change from

```
class _RectAnsState extends State<RectAns> {
```

to

```
class RectAnsState extends State<RectAns> {
```

Comment: @freeman3020 : Did you mean to ask if it is not advised in the best practices guide?

Answer (score 3):

Instead of

```
_RectAnsState createState() => _RectAnsState();
```

write this:

```
State<RectAns> createState() => _RectAnsState();
```

Answer (score 1):

The `State` class should be private indicating it should not be created anywhere outside createState override, because you should not create/manage `State` object instance at all (see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43874673/13737975.) and [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=d_m5csmrf7I)).

In your case you don't create/manage `State` object but only need to access already created object through key. Same mechanism exists in Flutter official widgets like [Form](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Form-class.html). There you have validation function `bool validate()` stored in Form's `State` class, so to access it you need an instance of `FormState`. You can obtain it from global key like this:

```
GlobalKey gk = GlobalKey(); // Notice that it's untyped!
GlobalKey typedGK = GlobalKey<FormState>(); // FormState has to be public

void myCallback() {
  // untyped, so code fails as it doesn't know validate() exists :(
  gk.currentState.validate();
  // typed, so everything is fine
  typedGK.currentState.validate();
}

Widget build(...) {
  return Form(
    key: gk,
    ...
  );
}
```

So Flutter official widgets use this mechanism if they need typed access to `State` object and obtain this object through key. Hence it should be perfectly fine to repeat this pattern in our own widgets.

Outside of that I can't think of a "good" reason to make your `State` class public and it's better to keep it private.