# How can I use Vertical and Horizontal drag and Scalein the Same GestureDetector?

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm trying to create a map in flutter and I have this rectangle which I can Scale using a `GestureDetector` and the `onScaleStart`, `onScaleUpdate` and `onScaleEnd` events  like showed in this answer: [How do I pan and zoom an image?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43651708/how-do-i-pan-and-zoom-an-image) and I tried adding `onHorizontalDrag` and `onVerticalDrag` but when I do so I get an error stating that I can't have them three at the same time or they'll interfere. So how can I do if I want to have the functionality of a basic map display like (Drag in both directions and scale)? Is there a faster and cleaner way of doing it than using a GestureDetector?

Comment: see https://stackoverflow.com/a/55324411/2252830

Answer (score 1):

I think you just need to use the Scale gesture. It's a superset of Pan. which is a single point gesture for both vertical and horizontal movements.